# Metric connection on a vector bundle at a point where the Riemannian metric of the base is standard to second order

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, connections

Let $E\to M$ be a smooth complex vector bundle with a hermitian metric, over a Riemannian manifold $M$, and let $\nabla$ be a metric connection on $E$. Suppose at a point $p\in M$, there is a coordinate neighborhood $(U,x_1,\dots,x_n)$ centered at $p$ such that the Riemannian metric of $M$ is standard to second order at $p$ (so that $g_{ij}(p)=\delta_{ij}$ and and the first-order partial derivatives of $g_{ij}$ vanishes at $p$). Then why is it true that $\nabla_{\partial_i}=\partial_i$ at $p$? (This is asserted in p.46 of Morgan's book on Seiberg-Witten Theory but I can't see why).

Comment: Do you need this for an arbitrary bundle? For the tangent space this is simply https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates around the point.

Comment: @quarague Yes, in the book $E$ is not necessarily the tangent bundle.

Comment: Your first sentence mentions a complex vector bundle $E$. It, however, is not used or mentioned in the rest of the question, which is about a Riemannian metric and its connection.

Comment: This is a standard trick when doing computations. I'll ignore the first sentence and discuss only the Levi-Civita connection. If you choose coordinates near $p$ such that $g_{ij}(p) = \delta_{ij}$ and $\partial_kg_{ij}(p) = 0$, then the Christoffel symbols also all vanish at $p$. Then, for example, if you have a $1$-form $\theta = a_i\,dx^i$, then its covariant derivative satisfies $\nabla_j\theta(p) = \partial_ja_i(p)\,dx^i$. This also works for higher order tensors. You can check this by writing the formula for the covariant derivative in local coordinates and then restricting to $p$.

Comment: If you want to do the same for the covariant derivative of a section of a vector bundle, you have to show that there is a local frame of sections whose covariant derivatives vanish at $p$.